# Installing and using D3 with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, npm, create-react-app

I am trying to use D3 with React and after doing `npm install d3`, i am importing it as such `import * as d3 from 'd3';`, after which I am getting this error.

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.../node_modules/d3/d3.js'
```

Any suggestions as to why?

Thanks!

Comment: Alright. Have you tried a fresh install to see what happens? `npm i -S d3 && rm -rf ./node_modules && npm i`

Comment: @Tholle yeah, i did that and unfortunately it messed up my html webpack plugin :(

Comment: @Tholle ok the html webpack plugin seems to be working fine (my mistake), but i'm getting the same error as before

Comment: Try removing node_modules folder and again hit npm install. Or "npm cache clean" and then install the dependencies.

Comment: @KrinaSoni I deleted the node modules, after which i did `npm install` and i get this error: `npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME` & `npm ERR! Invalid package name "@babel-core": name can only contain URL-friendly characters`

Comment: Fixed it using Bower install D3